# Is there a linting rule that disallows the use of rounded brackets after a return statement

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Using ESLint, I'm searching for a rule that will **not** allow the following:

```
return (
   <View />
);
```

But will allow:

```
return <View />;
```

After some searching, I wasn't able to find a matching rule. Can you help me?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you not allow the first syntax? It's great if you have complex/nested JSX.

Comment: I find that adding '(' and ')' doesn't make the code more readable. When you apply the right indentation, you achieve the same result. However, I'll guess I'll keep it like this when it is common/advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rule for this but it is a best practice to have a nested JSX